# error "Failed to find provider..." with facebook integration in my android app

Tags: android, facebook, integration

I'm developing an android application that is supposed to integrate with Facebook.
I'm going with Facebook tutorial about how to do it, but I keep getting this error for some days already.
I have the Facebook application installed in my android emulator, and configured my key hash in Facebook. (I've tried cygwin but it didn't work, so I did it in 3 different steps as I read in other questions)

I went over all the related questions, and I just can't get an answer.
all I get is the error, and a blank page with "facebook" sign above it.

EDIT:
now i'm also getting a message:
"MyApp is misconfigured for facebook login. press okay to go back to the application without connecting it to facebook."

my code:

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    Facebook facebook;
    private SharedPreferences prefs;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        facebook = new Facebook(getString(R.string.facebookAppId));

        prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        String access_token = prefs.getString("access_token", null);
        long expires = prefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);
        if(access_token != null) {
            facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
        }
        if(expires != 0) {
            facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
        }
        if(!facebook.isSessionValid()) {

            facebook.authorize(this, new String[] {"email", "read_friendlists"}, new DialogListener() {
                public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                    editor.putString("access_token", facebook.getAccessToken());
                    editor.putLong("access_expires", facebook.getAccessExpires());
                    editor.commit();
                }
                public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
                    System.out.println("onFacebookError()");
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
                public void onError(DialogError e) {}
                public void onCancel() {}
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try{
            facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }finally{
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {    
        super.onResume();
        //extend facebook session
        facebook.extendAccessTokenIfNeeded(this, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide complete error stack?

Comment: all I get is  Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider"

Comment: Can you edit your answer and post the complete stack trace? Or is that the only error line.

Comment: Have you made sure a) you are connected to the internet b) logged into the facebook app and c) the facebook app is up to date?  I work at Facebook and if you have any valid repro steps it'll help a lot to figure out why you and other devs are getting this error.

Comment: I'm connected both to the internet and to the facebook application, and the application was installed a week ago and it is the most up to date application.

Comment: I edited the question, i'm getting a new message now.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.
for people getting the same problem, so, i don't know why but if you make the login activity as main activity, it will leave a blank page and do nothing.
but after I've changed it to be called only clicking a button, it showed me the error, and when I printed the stack-trace, i found in the logcat my real hash-key.
after all, it was just a problem with the hash key, in windows the facebook instructions  don't work well.